# Making a list of rules from the list of elements

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Starting from the list:

```
{f[q1, q2], f[q3, q4], g[q1], g[q2, q3, q4], d[k1 - q1], d[k2 - q2 - q3 -q4]}
```

I would like to get the result:

```
{f[q1, q2] -> g[q1], f[q1, q2] -> g[q2, q3, q4], f[q3, q4] -> g[q2, q3, q4], f[q3, q4] -> g[q2, q3, q4], g[q1] -> k1, g[q2, q3, q4] -> k2}
```

by applying following two rules: first for all $q_i$ variables match $f[]$
to $g[]$ that contain the same $q_i$. If $f[]$ and $g[]$ contain more then 
one $q_i$ that is the same, then repeat the rule for each of such $q_i$, as in case of

```
f[q3, q4] -> g[q2, q3, q4]
```

Second rule should mach $g[]$ to a given $k_i$ that are again related by the corresponding $q_j$ in $d[]$ element. 
In case of multiple $q_j$ relating $g[]$ to a given $k_i$ only 
one rule will suffice, as in case of

```
g[q2, q3, q4] -> k2
```

How do I make a function that would produce such a list of rules for a 
given input list?

Note:
Element $d[...]$ in the input list can be thought of as a delta function setting the external momenta.

Eventually I want to use the obtained rules to make a `GraphPlot` that corresponds to  the Feynman diagram. Repeated rules then correspond to loops in a diagram.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basics of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. When you see good ones, please vote them up by clicking the grey triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. As you receive help, try to give it too, by *answering questions* in your area of expertise.

Comment: There are things to do after [your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), but don't rush, you may want stay vigilant some time after you get the first answer as its is likely that the best approaches may come later improving over a previous reply. Therefore, its a good idea to wait a few hours before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the deserving answers and [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you. (Links contain useful information))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f, g, q1, q2, q3, d, k1, k2]
```

your list:

```
flist = {f[q1, q2], f[q3, q4], g[q1], g[q2, q3, q4], d[k1 - q1], d[k2 - q2 - q3 - q4]}
```

### First set of rules

**Without repeated rules**

Make a list of all possible combinations of `f[_]` and `g[_]` using [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html), then [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) the ones with [`IntersectingQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntersectingQ.html) arguments, and change [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) from [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) to [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) using [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) (`@@`, `@@@`)

```
Rule @@@ Select[
  Tuples[
   {
    Select[flist, Head[#] == f &],
    Select[flist, Head[#] == g &]
    }],
  IntersectingQ[List @@ #[[1]], List @@ #[[2]]] &
  ]
```

> ```
> {f[q1, q2] -> g[q1], f[q1, q2] -> g[q2, q3, q4], f[q3, q4] -> g[q2, q3, q4]}
> ```

**With repeated rules**

Make a list of all possible combinations of `f[_]` and `g[_]` using [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html), then repeat each combination the number of common arguments. Then change [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) from [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) to [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) using [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) (`@@`, `@@@`)

```
Rule @@@ Flatten[
  Table[#, {Length[Intersection[List @@ #[[1]], List @@ #[[2]]]]}] & /@
  Tuples[{Select[flist, Head[#] == f &], Select[flist, Head[#] == g &]}], 1]
```

### Second set of rules

Now depending how the second set of rules is defined:

**If by the arguments in `g[_]`:**

(*this matches your example, but may no be what you meant, see also the next interpretation*)

[`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) the `g[_]`, take the fist argument and replace "q" for "k" , and change [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) from [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) to [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) using [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) (`@@@`)

```
Rule @@@ (
  {#, ToExpression@
      StringReplace[ToString[First[List @@ #]], "q" -> "k"]} & /@ 
   Select[flist, Head[#] == g &]
  )
```

**If by the arguments in `d[_]`:**

```
Block[{dlist = Select[flist, Head[#] == d &], arglist, ks, gs},
 arglist = First /@ List @@@ dlist;
 ks = Select[#, StringMatchQ[ToString[#], "k" ~~ __] &] & /@ arglist;
 gs = If[ListQ[#], g @@ #, g@#] & /@ (List @@@ (ks - arglist));
 Rule @@@ Transpose[{gs, ks}]
 ]
```

> ```
> {g[q1] -> k1, g[q2, q3, q4] -> k2}
> ```

Now you can just join the two lists of `Rules`

Comment: The arguments by `d[_]` is what I had in mind... sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In the 'First set of rules' the rule `f[q3, q4] -> g[q2, q3, q4]` should appear twice since there are two _q_-s that are matched.

Comment: I want to use rules to make a `GraphPlot`. Repeated rule then corresponds to a loop in the Feynman diagram i'm trying to construct.